# Android like calendar for Date calculations in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I am looking for an android like calendar in dart so that date manipulations can be easy. I want to get dates in reference to today's date. eg - date 1 month back, 3 months back, 1 year back etc. I can do that by subtracting 30 days from today but some months have 30 days, some have 31, 28 or 29. In such cases the dates I get are not exact. For this purpose, android's calendar was perfect. But I am looking for something like that in dart/flutter. Thanks in advance.

```
Android:
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(ToDaysDate);
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
Date Date1MonthBack = cal.getTime();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -3);
Date Date3MonthsBack = cal.getTime();

Dart/Flutter: ??????/
```